# Not getting date of birth from Facebook sdk 3.2 in iOS

Tags: ios, facebook

I have used Facebook sdk 3.2 in my app, i want to fetch all detail of my my profile, but it does not give to me birthday.

I have used the code:

```
[FBRequestConnection
     startForMeWithCompletionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection,
                                       id<FBGraphUser> user,
                                       NSError *error) {
         if (!error) {


         }
     }];
```

Can anyone explain where am i wrong here?

Any help would be appreciated.

Thnaks in advance.

Comment: now the ver 3.2 does not support at now, u need to use the new sdk 3.14

Comment: use this link for download the new sdk https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/

Comment: can it be Facebook APPid issue? because i am getting all data from old Facebook app id.

Comment: is not a big problem use the same app id , u need help use this reference https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/getting-started/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After version 3.13 if you are asking permission other than public_profile, email, and user_friends then you have to submit your app for review else you will not get it, thats why you are not able to get user_birthday. As written [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/upgrading)

> Developers asking for more than public_profile, email, and user_friends will need to submit their apps for review by Facebook to approve the permissions the app will request. See the Permissions Guide for details. Existing apps have one year before they are required to go through review, including updates to existing apps. Apps created after April 30th, 2014 must go through review.

Answer (score 1):

```
NSArray *arrFBPermissions = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects: @"user_birthday",@"email",nil];
[FBSession openActiveSessionWithReadPermissions:arrFBPermissions
                                   allowLoginUI:YES
                              completionHandler:
 ^(FBSession *session, FBSessionState state, NSError *error) {

     if (error == nil) {

         [FBRequestConnection startWithGraphPath:@"me?fields=id,name,birthday" completionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error) {

             if (error == nil) {

                 NSLog(@"FB user detail %@",result);

             }else {

                 UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error" message:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Following error occured:%@",error] delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"dismiss" otherButtonTitles: nil];
                 [alert show];

             }
         }];

     }else {

         UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error" message:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Following error occured:%@",error] delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"dismiss" otherButtonTitles: nil];
         [alert show];

     }
 }];
```

You need to provide FacebookAppID, add it into url scheme and bundle identifier should be same as you mentioned on facebook.

[image: You can check it on developer.facebook.com graph api tool]

Answer (score 0):

For getting date of birth you have retrieve data from FBGraphUser like this

```
[[FBRequest requestForMe] startWithCompletionHandler:
     ^(FBRequestConnection *connection,
       NSDictionary<FBGraphUser> *user,
       NSError *error) {
         if (!error) {
             NSString *firstName = user.first_name;
             NSString *lastName = user.last_name;
             NSString *bDay = user.birthday;
             NSString *facebookId = user.id;
             NSString *email = [user objectForKey:@"email"];
             NSString *imageUrl = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat: @"http://graph.facebook.com/%@/picture?type=large", facebookId];
             NSLog(@"%@, %@ , %@ , %@ ,%@ ,%@",bDay,firstName,lastName,facebookId,email,imageUrl);
         }
     }];
```